# What is the tradition of wearing bangles for some days after marriage?

Tags: marriage, tradition

In North India, I observe that my female colleagues wear bangles(and a lot of them) for some days after their marriage.

I have tried googling it, but haven't found much help from google. **So, what exactly is the tradition called?**

**And also, is there any specific amount of time(days) for which they are supposed to wear the bangles?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am posting the answer based on this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Choora&oldid=685002574).

This tradition is known as **Choora Ceremony**.

```
Choorae (plural) may contain different coloured bangles in various combinations,
but the most common combination is red and white. The choora is worn by the bride
for 40 days from the day she puts it on and on the 40th day only her husband can
remove it for her.
```